# Adding unused types into the directives property of Component has any consequences?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Adding several unused types to the directives property of the Component decorator in Angular2 is the same as adding the correct directives?
I mean, is the compiler smart enough to output the exact same result within the JS file?

*EDIT:*
I made a tiny test. I added a COMMON_DIRECTIVES and some of my own directives to a component that didn't use all of them. Got both js and used FileMerge to compare. Both are equal. But I will leave this open, maybe someone has more to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a longer engineering-centric answer here:

https://gist.github.com/matanlurey/0fec1ac15a7a80c898870546123b70b3

tl;dr, as filiph mentioned, we are *very* conservative. We are looking to address this in a future version of AngularDart, but it will likely be a breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the compiler is conservative about treeshaking these — so adding directives will add their code to the deployed app even if you don't use them. This is because AngularDart can't be 100% sure that you won't be using those components dynamically.